Computer won’t boot past BIOS
Hardware:

MB: ASUS ROG Strix B550 Gaming Wifi 2
CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 12-core
RAM: 2x16 G-Skill DDR4-3200
GPU: ASUS ROG Nvidia 4060
SSD: WD Blue 1TB

Computer will not load past the BIOS setup screen. I can get into the BIOS no problem and make changes without issue, but no matter how I try to boot it simply restarts the computer. In the BIOS it shows that everything appears nominal, a.k.a. fan speeds are fine, CPU temp and MB temps are fine, RAM is recognized. BIOS is also up to date using a USB installer from the ASUS website. Also, none of the lights on the MB stay on besides the Boot light but it only stays on until the computer restarts, which is immediately following the BIOS screen. It has even gotten to the ASUS screen and started spinning with "Preparing for automatic repair" but it does not stay there long before rebooting.
Final note: This is a new MB (and CPU) after the last one started doing the same thing, but I ended troubleshooting on that one when I had exhausted my options on a CPU red light issue, ultimately believing the MB to be bad (or possibly CPU but I dont believe so)
Troubleshooting I have done (and not in any particular order):

Rebooted the computer after clearing the CMOS and CMOS-RAM (shorting the pins as per the manual), including a new battery.
Disconnected and reconnected every plug and device, including reseating the CPU and RAM as well as trying 1 or both RAM sticks (and a few extras I have) in different configurations (1 in B2, 1 in B2 and 1 in A2, etc.)
Removing any non-essential hardware including the mouse and even the keyboard to see if it would boot in case one of the components was causing a short or failure to occur.
Using a different drive (an older 1TB HDD that worked last I knew) even though the MB recognizes both of them (which would show in the picture that all of the above hardware is readily recognized by the MB, including the fans)
I have even removed the board from the case and placed it on a wood surface to ensure that nothing is shorting from the board to the case somehow.

One thing I am unsure about but don’t want to spend more money on yet is that I couldn't find my exact RAM sticks in the compatible memory list on the ASUS website for this board.


did you remove HDD/SSD completely to see how it acts? Try to remove everything except motherboard, CPU, one RAM, disconnect GPU if PC has onboard video, no cables except one to monitor & power, after a first boot then connect keyboard. Report results. 3a)sounds like windows corruption and/or BIOS misconfiguration, have you factory reset it? 3b) what happens when you boot to windows/Linux CD/USB drive?



As mentioned above, try booting from USB, e.g., Linux live or Win PE/RE. 2. Try minimal RAM installation for that board, with known good RAM.


I removed the drives and any non-essentials (including the keyboard and mouse, which the MB informed me of before it reached the BIOS setup screen) and it still will not make it past the BIOS screen. I cannot disconnect the GPU as the CPU does not have integrated graphics. The RAM I tried should not be an issue as it is brand new (not part of the original 4 sticks I had at the start of the issue) though I tried those individually anyways. Issue was not resolved. I have tried to boot using a USB but I cannot even make it to a boot screen period. I will try a factory reset and see what happens.

Apparently I was right that the original motherboard went bad but apparently the new Ryzen 9 5900X and ASUS ROG Strix Gaming Wifi 2 MB combo I bought either weren't compatible (seems unlikely if they sold as a pair) or I got a faulty CPU because I tried my old Ryzen 7 in the new MB and it finally works.
A little frustrating to buy a new CPU (and a few other new things) and not have it work but I guess thats my luck.

Depending on the storefront there is absolutely no guarantee that compatibility was even considered. Amazon often will suggest items along with a product and in the past those products were not compatible (say a third-party charger with some device that requires a charger). It’s also possible the firmware just needed to be updated.
